# How can we access topmost formControll in a validator function of a nested formgroup?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

How can we access the entire form inside a validator function.

i tried giving control.parent.parent  ,but its throwing an error.

```
private unitNumberValidator(hasMdu){
  return (control: AbstractControl)=>{
  let returnVal = null;
//here i want to access entire form 
  console.log(control.parent.parent);

return returnVal;
}
}
```

how can we achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much @yurzui ,I've been stuck on this for 3 hours,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `root` getter like:

```
<FormGroup>control.root
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#root

Comment: let p=<FormGroup>control.root;
    console.log( p.get("radioSelection").value,"ddd");
i am getting an error whille accessing the value;
formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Comment: Can you create plunker to reproduce it?

Comment: <FormGroup>control.root.get("radioSelection") is working fine. the error is coming only when i try to access value, i will try to set up a plunker soon

Comment: in the console.log if you remove the .value  then it will return the formcontroll